# Have data-live-search interpret &nbsp; the same as normal space (&#32;)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ascii, bootstrap-select

I am using data-live-search with [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) and am running into a problem where the blank spaces used in my options are not interpreted the same as a normal space. I would like to have   replaced by a normal blank space. Was wondering if there is any easy way to fix this? [Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jackmoody11/sfffqs8e/) of the problem. Code is below as well (per SO rules).

```
<body>
 <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
  <select class="selectpicker" title='Choose one of the following...' data-live-search="true">
        <option>Option&nbsp;1</option>
        <option>Option&nbsp;2</option>
        <option>Option&nbsp;3</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no option o configuration to achieve your goal.

Probably the simplest way to do that is using jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".selectpicker option").each(function(index) {
    var txt = $(this).html().replace("&nbsp;", " ");
    $(this).html(txt);
    console.log(index + ": ", this);
  });
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<label>Select live search</label>
<select class="selectpicker" title='Choose one of the following...' data-live-search="true">
      <option>Option&nbsp;1</option>
      <option>Option&nbsp;2</option>
      <option>Option&nbsp;3</option>
      <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm using Rails, so I feel like there is probably an easier way than to use more Javascript. Was thinking about maybe using a gsub. This is a good answer, but I was looking for a way to replace it.